# Openshift server service temporarily unavailable

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

Created a MEAN stack app.
When added mongoose in my server.js file and added it to openshift the app stopped working. It shows
Service temporarily unavailable.

**server.js code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); 
var passport      = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var session       = require('express-session');
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myproject');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserSchema);

var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var port= process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, ip);
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MyProject CS5610",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Pankaj Tripathi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.4",
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "express-session": "^1.10.4",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.25",
    "multer": "^0.1.8",
    "passport": "^0.2.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

}

**rhc tail shows following error:**

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/openshift/552644dffcf933d46400014d/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
[myproject-pankajt.rhcloud.com 552644dffcf933d46400014d]> ls
app-deployments  app-root  git  mongodb  nodejs
[myproject-pankajt.rhcloud.com 552644dffcf933d46400014d]> timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
Connection to myproject-pankajt.rhcloud.com closed.

Comment: are you sure that `npm install` is run on target machine and all dependencies are there?

Comment: yup all the dependencies were mentioned in package.json file and everything was installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

this statement did the job.

```
var connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/myproject';
mongoose.connect(connectionString)
```

Answer (score -1):

change

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "server app.js"
  },
"engines": {
"node": ">= 0.6.0",
"npm": ">= 1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: made the change...unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: are you sure that the `server.js` and `package.json` on the same directory 
if not change the script part to `"start" : "<PATH_TO_SERVER.JS>" `

Comment: yup they are in the same directory

Comment: Hi, I changed my connection string and it worked. var connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/myproject';
mongoose.connect(connectionString)